# Keras and pytorch CNN model gives two different output shape

Tags: conv-neural-network, shapes

I have a following Keras model

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import Input
X_2D = Input(shape=(1,5000,1)) # Input is EEG signal 1*5000 with channel =1
cnn2d = Conv2D(32, (1,10),activation='relu')(X_2D) # filters=32, kernel= (1,10)
print(X_2D.shape,'->',cnn2d.shape)
```

The output is: (1, 5000, 1) -> (None, 1, 4991, 32)

I tried to implement the same in pytorch

```
a = torch.randn(1,5000,1)  
m = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, (10,1)) # filters=32, kernel= (10,1)
out = m(a)
print(out.size())
```

The output is:torch.Size([32, 4991, 1])

The channel is placed different in the keras and pytorch convolutional model. How can I get the same shape?
Thank you very much